# has anyone used braintree for token based transactions?

Tags: php, token, braintree

i am trying to understand how to use braintree but their documents are becomeing hard to understand after all the errors that i am receiving.

what i am trying to do is submit customer billing information + credit card information to then receive a token so that i can store it in a db.

this is what i wrote and i am getting errors.

```
<?php
  include_once("lib/Braintree.php"); //braintree library
  include_once("config.php"); //the Braintree_Configurations



  $result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
      'firstName' => 'Mike',
      'lastName' => 'Jones',
      'company' => 'Jones Co.',
      'email' => 'mike.jones@example.com',
      'phone' => '419.555.1234',
      'fax' => '419.555.1235',
      'website' => 'http://example.com',
      'creditCard' => array(
          'number' => '5105105105105100',
          'expirationDate' => '05/12',
          'cvv' => '123',
          'cardholderName' => 'Mike Jones',
          'billingAddress' => array(
              'firstName' => 'Drew',
              'lastName' => 'Smith',
              'company' => 'Smith Co.',
              'streetAddress' => '1 E Main St',
              'extendedAddress' => 'Suite 101',
              'locality' => 'Chicago',
              'region' => 'IL',
              'postalCode' => '60622',
              'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US'
          )
      )
  ));






  if ($result->success) {
      print_r("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
  } else if ($result->transaction) {
      print_r("Error processing transaction:");
      print_r("\n  message: " . $result->message);
      print_r("\n  code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
      print_r("\n  text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText);
  } else {
      print_r("Message: " . $result->message);
      print_r("\nValidation errors: \n");
      print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
  }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line 'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US' and your code will work.
One thing more the result does not have transaction object which you are using like '$result->transaction->id'.